# React and Redux: How do I get the value of my application's state/Redux store at any point in my app?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a reactjs web app. I want to make a request to server and want to include the whole state of the app. How do I achieve this?

Comment: Why are you attempting to send the entirety of application state to the service on request? Although this is possible, this is not good practice.

Comment: We want to track the state of application in certain buggy scenarios so that we can debug better

Comment: I assume you want the production snapshot? In development you can use other tools like logger or devtools. Another option would be to use a store listener, then store it in a variable to be used by your fetch call.

Comment: I found this npm module called redux bug reporter: https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-bug-reporter. It kind of solves my problem since it captures the state while sending the request. I tweaked this and got my task done.

Answer (score 0):

So basically you need to have the entire store created with createstore library before doing any web call with the state (http://redux.js.org/docs/api/createStore.html) . You can structure your tree in such a way that you can group it as per your wish using combine reducer. (http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/UsingCombineReducers.html). An example would be

```
export default combineReducers({
  stateVariable1 : Reducer1,
  stateVariable2 : Reducer2...
});
```

Each reducer should be considered as a part of a state which you want to group. (http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/NormalizingStateShape.html)

Then in any component of your app you can use connect library to connect it with the state tree for dispatching actions, fetching state items. Also you can mention which part of the state tree you want to get access.

For example

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  Reducer1 : StateVariable1 // Reducer1 in component can be accessed as this.props.Reducer1
});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  quickinvestListingsActions : bindActionCreators(quickinvestListingsActions, dispatch) // Dispatching actions
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(QuickInvestListings); // This connects the component with the redux state
```

So you can use Reducer1 for any purpose including sending request